# Hibernate Lazy Loaded Object Throws Error Due to Detached From Session

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, lazy-loading

I'm using some legacy hibernate code which was set up to use lazy loading.

I'm attempting to improve performance by caching often used values that change very rarely to avoid database calls. So I've implemented a HashMap to store 3 values in.

What I want to happen is to cache a lazy-loaded entity after the session is closed and make use of the data held in that entity.

In the method I'm having issues with, I look up the parent object and then also retrieve an associated lazy loaded child object. Both of these are stored in the HashMap.

```
hashMap = PARENT = ParentType.class
          CHILD = ChildType.class
```

This mostly works fine except intermittently I'm seeing that the CHILD field suddenly contains the following error code rather than the object that was populated.

```
hashMap = PARENT = ParentType.class
          CHILD = Exception occurred in target VM: could not initialize     proxy - no Session
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
            at     org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:149)
            at     org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:195)
            at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:185)
            at webpay.cryptolib.bean.KeyTypes_$$_javassist_9.toString(KeyTypes_$$_javassist_9.java)
            at webpay.ksl.DekManager.putCryptoKey(DekManager.java:378)
            at webpay.ksl.DekManager.getDekValue(DekManager.java:225)
            at webpay.ksl.KeyService.encrypt(KeyService.java:116)
            at webpay.ksl.KeyService.encrypt(KeyService.java:146)
            at webpay.crypto.CardCrypt.encryptAndStoreOrNone(CardCrypt.java:116)
            at webpay.engine.transaction.creditcard.CreditcardTransaction.insertTransaction(CreditcardTransaction.java:1066)
            at webpay.engine.transaction.creditcard.CreditcardTransaction.init(CreditcardTransaction.java:261)
            at webpay.engine.TransactionFactory.makeTransaction(TransactionFactory.java:166)
            at webpay.engine.TransactionFactory.makeTransaction(TransactionFactory.java:98)
            at webpay.engine.TransactionFactory.makeTransaction(TransactionFactory.java:85)
            at webpay.engine.TransactionHandler.serviceSocket(TransactionHandler.java:164)
            at matrix.net.SocketDispatcher$SocketThread.run(SocketDispatcher.java:296)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Now I understand this indicates that there's no session and this is correct as the session is closed once the CHILD is retrieved. However this CHILD is now cached and should be detached but still viable for use.

The method being used to populate this is:

```
 public ParentType getCurrentContainer() throws InvalidSystemException, NoParentTypeFoundException{
Session session = null;
 if (!isCacheValid()) {
   try {
      session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(getSystemName()).openSession();
      Criteria dekQuery = session.createCriteria(ParentType.class, "pt");
      dekQuery.add(Restrictions.and(Restrictions.eq("pt.status", DekStatus.CURRENT.toString())));
        if (!dekQuery.list().isEmpty()) {
          ParentType pt = (ParentType) dekQuery.list().get(0);
          putCryptoKey(PARENT_CRYPTO_KEY, pt);

          //Extract lazy load keytype
          KeyTypes keyType = pt.getKeyType();
          putCryptoKey(KEY_TYPE_CRYPTO_KEY, keyType);
          logger.debug("Current ParentType found - ParentType Id : {}", pt.getDekId());
          logger.debug("Current KeyType found - KeyType Id : {}", keyType.getKeyTypeId());

       } else {
          logger.info("No Current pt found");
          throw new NoDekFoundException("No pt found with status CURRENT");
       }
} finally {
if (session != null && session.isOpen()) {
session.close();
}
}
}
return (ParentType) cryptoKeys.get(PARENT_CRYPTO_KEY);
}
```

My guess is that when i load the lazy object it doesn't load, and when i next reference it it attempts to load from the parent (which is also cached). At this point there is no session so the error is thrown.

Is there a way to force the lazy object into existence instead of allowing hibernate to decide?

Comment: paste your hibernate.cfg.xml here.